# How can we access TFS on premises server with VSTS CALS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We want to access our on premises TFS with VSTS CALs. We were trying it with the following information from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com.

[image]

We created a user in VSTS with Basic level permissions.  It allowed us to create with the email ID of the user. Where as we can not login to the TFS Server with the email ID.

We didn't understand how the VSTS license integrates with our TFS on premises.

Please let us know how we can use VSTS CALs to access TFS Server.

Comment: They don't integrate.  You get a _license_ - a legal agreement to use the product.  It doesn't set up authentication for you.  If you want to use TFS, you'll need to manage the permissions and accounts in TFS.  If you want to use VSTS, you'll need to manage the permissions and accounts in VSTS.  There's no automatic synchronization between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Edward said in the comment, you must first configure your VSTS account have the corresponding access and permission in TFS server.

For example,  if you have a domain account `company/Ram Datla` / `Ram Datla@company.com` and the user have add in your local TFS server.

> For TFS you pay per user for team members who need to use Basic
>   features like Code or Agile Planning. Team members who have a Visual
>   Studio subscription are free to add because Basic features are
>   included in their subscription as a benefit.

If you haven't paid for this  `Ram Datla@company.com` account. You could also be able to access  TFS server ,  however just  as a **stakeholders**, which provides access to a limited set of features. It's also free to add stakeholders to TFS.

If you have paid for the `Ram Datla@company.com` account  with Basic level, then you could also use this account to also have Basic level(who need to use Basic features like Code or Agile Planning) in your local TFS server. Thus you don't have to pay this user again.

---

> *Q: Why should I pay via VSTS for my TFS users?*
>
> *A: You get many benefits, for example:*
>
> - Paying via VSTS gives your users the flexibility to access both TFS    and VSTS for the same price.
> - You can pay monthly for users who need temporary access.
> - You get all the purchasing capabilities that Azure offers, like    payment via credit card, through a Cloud Solution Provider (CSP)
>     partner, through the Enterprise Agreement, and more.

Suggest you first go through below links with more detail explain of pricing:

- [Team Foundation Server Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/)
- [Buy access to Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub)

Also take a look at  the different **[Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/about-vsts-tfs#authentication)** of TFS and VSTS.

Comment: Thank You all for sharing your knowledge.